# Cookies are not removing on Log Out

Tags: php

I've got a problem, user can't Log Out because the $_COOKIE's are not actually deleting. I can't find out what could be the problem.

This code is used only once at Log In:

```
// Log In
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
setcookie('user_id', $row['user_id'], time() + 2592000);
setcookie('username', $row['username'], time() + 2592000);
```

The code below is checking if cookies are set up to make users to be logged in when they relaunch their browser (the "keep me logged in" effect).

```
// Starting Session
session_start();
// If the session vars aren't set, try to set them with cookies
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    // This check always equals true because cookies are not deleting on Log Out
    if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
    }
}
```

This code is launched only once on Log Out:

```
// Log Out
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $_SESSION = array();
    if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 2592000, '/');
    }
    session_destroy();
}
setcookie('user_id', '', time() - 2592000);
setcookie('username', '', time() - 2592000);
```

Comment: Cookies are 'live' at the next page request. If you refresh the page a user is still logged in? Also I heard problems with using (60 * 60 * 24 * 30), can't imagine why but just use a single value '2592000' is faster too. Maybe add a comment it is one month (or put it in a define!)

Comment: Yes, the user is still logged in :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why cookies were not removing!

To make sure your cookies will remove, set the same path on removing cookies as on setting them.

```
// Setting Cookie
setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-2592000, '/'); // The path here is "/"

// Removing Cookie
setcookie(session_name(), '', time()+2592000, '/'); // The path here is "/"
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use relative times for cookies. if you want to expire a cookie, then use `Jan 1 1970 00:00:00`. You're assuming that the user's clock is accurate and within an hour of your server's. Given how many people have their VCRs blinking `12:00`, this is a bad assumptiong.

As well, why are you storing login information in a client-side cookie? The only cookie you should really be setting is the session cookie, which session_start() already does for you, then store all that information in $_SESSION only.

Comment: How to expire cookies with the "Jan 1 1970 00:00:00"?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're doing it way too complicated.
My example where it's just an admin login:

login.php

```
@session_start();
if (isset($_GET['login'])) {
    if($_GET['name'] == $s['admin']){
        if($_GET['pw'] == $s['adminpw']){
            $_SESSION['isadmin'] = true;    
        }
    }
}
```

logout.php

```
@session_start();
unset ($_SESSION['isadmin']);
```

use `session_set_cookie_params()` to set the lifetimes

Comment: if `session_start()` is already performed another `session_start()` will throw errors but just result in nothing. So I just always go with `@session_start()` . In this example, of course, it's not needed

Comment: What?! You should use `if(session_id() == '') session_start();` instead of `@`!